# How to manage directories in Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

The following Makefile should build a simple project

```
CC = gcc
INCDIRS = -Iinclude
CFLAGS = -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -g $(INCDIRS)

CFILES = char_list.c int_list.c main.c
OBJFILES = char_list.o int_list.o main.o

BINARY = main

BINDIR = bin/
OBJDIR = obj/

all: $(BINARY)

$(BINARY): $(OBJFILES)
    $(CC) -o $(TARGETDIR)$@ $(OBJDIR)$^

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $(OBJDIR)$@ $^

clean:
    @rm -rf $(BINARY) $(OBJFILES)
```

I've just started using Makefile for the first time, so i ran into a problem when trying to change the project folder structure and make it work with Makefile (folder structure at the end).
When I build the binary the rule asks for all the .o as shown, but since I wanted to organize my workspace a little better i choose to put all .o files in an obj folder.
I thought that putting the variable $(OBJDIR) beside the $^ would apply it to every OBJFILE, but i now know that it can't happen because $(OBJDIR) and $^ are treated similarly to strings, so this command just concatenates the two.

How can I make so that every word in OBJFILES gets the correct prefix?

```
.
├── bin
├── char_list.c
├── include
│   ├── char_list.h
│   └── int_list.h
├── int_list.c
├── main.c
├── Makefile
├── obj
│   ├── char_list.o
│   ├── int_list.o
│   └── main.o
└── parser_pseudo.txt
```

This is the error, as said, only the first .o gets the prefix

```
gcc -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -g -Iinclude -c -o obj/char_list.o char_list.c
gcc -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -g -Iinclude -c -o obj/int_list.o int_list.c
gcc -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -g -Iinclude -c -o obj/main.o main.c
gcc -o main obj/char_list.o int_list.o main.o
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find int_list.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find main.o: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:16: main] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2):

First, Makefiles just do string concatenation. So when you do this:

```
OBJFILES = char_list.o int_list.o main.o
OBJDIR = obj/

.PHONY: all

all:
    @echo $(OBJDIR)$(OBJFILES)
```

It will print this:

```
obj/char_list.o int_list.o main.o
```

In order to add prefixes to a list, use `$(addprefix prefix,names...)` like so:

```
OBJFILES = char_list.o int_list.o main.o
OBJDIR = obj/

.PHONY: all

all:
    @echo $(addprefix $(OBJDIR),$(OBJFILES))
```

But second, the targets and dependencies of your rules are no longer accurate, because you changed the output file paths in the commands, but didn't adjust the rest of the rule. So in general, I would recommend that you have the full, actual path of your files right there in the variables already. In order to save you a lot of typing and repetition, you can use `$(patsubst pattern,replacement,words...)`:

```
OBJDIR   := obj
CFILES   := char_list.c int_list.c main.c
OBJFILES := $(patsubst %.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(CFILES))

.PHONY: all

all:
    @echo $(OBJFILES)
```

Instead of listing the C files manually, you can also use `$(wildcard *.c)`, assuming you actually want all the C files in the project root.
And there's two more changes I made here:

1. The use of `:=` over `=`. This means that the right-hand side is evaluated at the time of the assignment rather than the time of use. With the regular `=`, if you write `$(OBJFILES)` 20 times in your Makefile, then the `$(patsubst ...)` will be performed 20 times, whereas with `:=` it will be performed only once. IMO you should use this whenever the variable you define is final and will not change at any time throughout the build process, and is not referenced before its definition.
2. The use of `.PHONY: all`. Since `./all` is not a file that will be created, you should inform `make` that this is the case. From here on out I will be using `.PHONY: all clean`.

Yet another change I'd make is the creation and deletion of folders. The simple reason for this is git. If you create an empty folder `obj/` in a git project, then there is no way for you to commit it. You could create a placeholder file inside it, but that's ugly. Instead, you can just modify the `%.o` rule to `$(OBJDIR)/%.o` and add an order-only dependency to it by appending `| $(OBJDIR)` to the end. Then all you need is a build rule for that like so:

```
$(OBJDIR):
    @mkdir -p $@
```

Now, since you've already declared `BINDIR` in your Makefile but used `$(TARGETDIR)` in the build rule, I'm assuming you want your binary to go into a folder as well. So all in all, I'd rewrite your Makefile like this:

```
CC       := gcc
INCDIRS  := -Iinclude
CFLAGS   := -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -g $(INCDIRS)

BINDIR   := bin
OBJDIR   := obj

BINARY   := $(BINDIR)/main

CFILES   := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJFILES := $(patsubst %.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(CFILES))

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(BINARY)

$(BINARY): $(OBJFILES) | $(BINDIR)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c | $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

$(BINDIR) $(OBJDIR):
    @mkdir -p $@

clean:
    @rm -rf $(BINDIR) $(OBJDIR)
```

NB: Stack Overflow's Markdown renderer converts all tabs to spaces, so make sure to convert them back if you copy anything.

Comment: Thank you! This is really useful information, Make is so powerful if used correctly